# WAMPSERVER: Can't load web page externally

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm having problems getting to view my web page through the global IP address.

I use Windows 8 Pro 64-bit and Arris DG860 router.

I downloaded WampServer (64 BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.4 and installed Apache service from Apache option on the green icon, since the service was not starting.

I added a virtual server in my router:

```
Name: HTTP 80-80
Type: Both (UDP & TCP)
Private IP Address: My machine's IPV4 address
Local Port: 80-80
```

I opened port 80 through my Windows firewall for TCP and UDP under HTTP name.

I changed httpd.conf file fields as follows:

```
#Controls who can get stuff from this server.
#
# Require all granted
# onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all <---- from this
Allow from all <---- to this
Allow from 127.0.0.1
Allow from ::1
Allow from localhost
</Directory>
```

When I type in localhost, my machine's IPV4 address or 127.0.0.1, the page comes up.

However, when I type in my global IPV4 address on that same computer, my Android Droid X Phone, my wife's Android Note 2 Phone or our all-in-one computer in the kitchen, none of them can load the page.

At first I thought that it could be an issue with my ports not being forwarded properly, so I turned off firewall on router and windows side, it didn't work.

Something in httpd.conf or other configuration file is not set properly, maybe I missed a step.

I haven't had any problems before with streaming videos from my security cameras, so I know that ISP is not blocking streaming traffic for port 80.

I did install Zoom Indexer afterwards, but I don't think it messes with any similar files?

**EDIT:**

Well, it works now. I can't say much to anyone who's having the same problem, except the fact that try to re-install Wampserver and try different configuration settings in httpd file.  Something worked for me.  I'm thinking ZoomSearch somehow messed with a Registry setting when it got installed after Wampserver and a few re-installs did the trick.  I wish I knew what the exactly the problem was, so that I could help out anyone with the same issue, but I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Left click on your Wamp icon in the status bar, and select "Put Online"  That very well may do the trick.

Comment: It's been Online.  That's the thing... nothing seem to work.  I even uninstalled it and Zoom and then re-installed WAMPSERVER.  I watched countless videos on YouTube and I'm not doing anything differently than any of them.  I then tried those little fixes I found online for Allow from all and such... and still nothing works.

Comment: When you type in the Global address, are all the devices connected to the same network as your host computer?  If that is the case, then they will be unable to resolve the global address, and instead you should use the local address.

Comment: I thought of it, that's why I used phones.  They're not on WiFi because I have unlimited data.  Anyways, I don't know what I did, but somehow I got it to work.  I'm able to access it now.  I kept on messing with different lines in the configuration file and got it running on my phones.  As an aside, since you mentioned it, is there a way to be able to access my website from local machine using global address?

Comment: To the best of knowledge, there is not a way.  It has been a while since I've looked into it, so someone who knows more about this sort of thing may have a method that works.